# Freeing struct that cointains double pointer

Tags: c, struct

Say I have a struct defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
int width;
int height;
char **data;
} puzzle;
```

Then, according to my textbook, the free function should look like this:

```
void puzzle_free(puzzle** puzzle)
```

But I don't see why puzzle should be a double pointer in the free function.

Comment: It would make sense if they expect the function to set the passed pointer to NULL after freeing.

Comment: It's not necessary to catch with double pointer but its depends how  `puzzle_free()` gets called and what argument  is passed in `puzzle_free()`

Comment: That's an odd thing to see, but like Eugene the only explanation I can think of is you squish the pointer once you free it. That is a very quirky design, and probably some attempt to avoid using a freed pointer, but since C is rife with problems like this it's a tiny fix for an endemic problem. Using a NULL pointer by accident is just as dangerous as using one that's been released.

Comment: the double pointer when passing the structure pointer to the puzzle_free function is not related to the type of data in the struct. please read your textbook again.

Comment: @tadman Setting freed pointer to null is useful for checking. I guess it's legit to have a design where some dynamic data structure is filled with such a pointers and `NULL` will indicate the invalid ones.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Some systems set pointers to `0xdeadbeef` or something distinctive so you can know if it was freed, or if it was always NULL. You can use your own nonsense values for this purpose, an invalid pointer is an invalid pointer.

Comment: @tadman Sure. The above `puzzle_free` can do this too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has nothing to do with the double pointer contained in the struct, but is just a way to write free functions that helps prevent access after free.
Eugene Sh. refers to it in his comment.

The implementation of `puzzle_free` would be:

```
void puzzle_free(puzzle** puzzle_p) {
    puzzle *puzzle = *puzzle_p
    // Somehow free puzzle->data
    free(puzzle);
    *puzzle_p = NULL;
}
```

And usage would be:

```
puzzle *puzzle = malloc(...)
// Fill it, use it.
puzzle_free(&puzzle);
// puzzle pointer is now NULL
```

Comment: How does this prevent access after free? Could there be a dangling pointer?

Comment: @Nerd, it does not completely prevent it. It helps prevent it, by setting this one pointer to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Well that depends. If you did this,

```
puzzle **a = malloc(sizeof *a * NUMITEMS);
for(size_t i = 0; i < NUMITEMS; i++)
   a[i]= malloc(sizeof *a[i] * NUMITEMS);
```

Then ofcourse free can be like this. `myfree(&puzzle);` - signature being `myfree(puzzle *** a)`.

Then if you had simply this,

```
puzzle* a = malloc(sizeof *a *NUMITEMS);
```

Then `myfree(&a)` (signature containing double pointer) would suffice. It depends on the what you are trying to free.

```
void myfree(puzzle **a){
    free(*a);
}
```

The way the book mentioned - it is safe to say that book used the kind of allocation shown in the second above. You have to pass the address of it because otherwise you will be making changes to a local variable. (This is why the double pointer is needed as mentioned by book).